# Adobe stopped Adobe Programs (Acrobat, Photoshop, Creatve Cloud Apps,...) running on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat, licensing

As I have installed the full Creative Cloud Suite on a Windows 7 machine, some day ago all programs, including Acrobat DC, stopped working.
At start, a pop-up windows tells, "Your subscription status cannot be confirmed."
A contact with Adobe support told, Adobe as stopped support for Windows 7.

But even I'm unable to run the programs in the state they have.

Any ideas to come around and get them working again?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Windows 10.

[Adobe supports only "two versions back"](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/system-requirements.html) which at time of writing is Windows 10 versions 1903 and later.

Windows 7 is dead & gone. No-one is going to be committed to supporting it any more. Microsoft's rapid shutdown of Win 7 support enabled companies to do what they're been hoping for for years - not to have to provide support for ancient operating systems.

Comment: Thats's not the full info.
According to [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/system-requirements.html) the required System for Acrobat DC Pro, for example, contains **Windows 7** and for the question `What should I do if I can't upgrade my operating system?` [this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/download-install/kb/operating-system-guidelines.html) says 
`If you can't upgrade your operating system right now, you can continue to use the currently installed version of your Creative Cloud apps for compatibility until you can upgrade.` Which is now not the case and contrary to your answer.

Comment: The final arbiter is Adobe… & if they won't help because they, according to your initial post "stopped support for Windows 7." then that's their call.